# Identifying a grassy plant from South Carolina

Tags: identification, grass, weeds

I’m trying to identity one of a couple of grassy plants that grows throughout my lawn.  This one looks like a sand burr, but doesn't seem to dry out and get prickly like those do. I live about 40 miles from the South Carolina coast.

[image: plant 1]

Comment: There's a site policy to have just one plant per id question; see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/826/for-identification-please-only-post-one-plant-per-question-and-be-specific-whe for more information. Please ask about the second plant in a separate question. Thanks and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plant piece in your photo is from a member of the "sedge" family (Cyperaceae). The plant is of unknown type/species/variety.  It might be what is commonly called a "nutsedge", and is considered a difficult to eradicate weed.  Sedges comprise a very large, grass-like, plant family, usually (but not always) characterized by their triangular stems (in cross section).  There are far too many genera/species to identify the exact type(s) that you have at your South Carolina location.  I have provided a few informative links below.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyperaceae

https://hgic.clemson.edu/factsheet/nutsedge/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyperus

Comment: That was my suspicion, but it never really looked quite like nutsedge. "Cyperus strigosus" (false nutsedge) seems really similar. Now to try to prevent it next season. Thanks for the links.